# How to tidy up on c++ error handling with return-values? (deallocation)

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, return-value

I will use library in a huge project where exceptions are used for error handling. The library uses return codes for their error handling, meaning all functions will return a constant, defining if the function succeeded or any error happened.

Very often my functions have to abort if the library functions fail. Any better way to handle these errors than in the example implementation as given on the following snippet?

A main concern of my question is about deallocating previously allocated memory after each evaluation of the return code. This is fault-prone and cumbersome. I hope to find some guideline to prevent the deallocation at each call of the library functions...

```
void examplefunc()
{
  T* pT = new T();
  U* pU = new U();
  Q myQ;
  int iRes = CONST_SUCCESS;

  if ((iRes = myQ.func1())!= CONST_SUCCESS)
  {
    delete pU;
    delete pT;
    throw translateException(iRes);  // providing exc      
  }
  if ((iRes = mQ.func2())!= CONST_SUCCESS)
  {
    delete pU;
    delete pT;
    throw translateException(iRes);  // providing exc 
  }

  delete pU;
  delete pT;
  return;
}
```

Thank you for all advice. Are there any guidelines I could follow?

Best regards
Sam

Answer (score 4):

Use smart pointers. E.g. instead of:

```
T* pT = new T();
```

you might use C++11's `unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> pT = make_unique<T>();
```

unique_ptr provides automatic destruction of the internal pointer as soon as the wrapping object gets out of scope.

Comment: Will be hard to mix up pointers and smart pointers in an existing project.

Comment: @user1708818 Well, depends on the complexity of the project and how carefully it was designed. Any pointer used internally by a function and never disclosed to the rest of the code can be safely translated in a smart pointer. If, instead, pointer types are used for object attributes or global references, it might not be so simple. Also, `unique_ptr` enriches the variable with the semantic of "pointer ownership", that is a good thing both from a design and documentation point of view.

Comment: There is no `std::make_unique`, although there probably should be. Herb Sutter provides a possible implementation: http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_102/, obviously if you put this in your code then it should be somewhere other than `namespace std`, and if it's added to the standard in future then whatever namespace you put your version in, you can replace the definition in your namespace with `using std::make_unique;` and/or set about finding all the callers and moving them to use `std` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should create some sort of wrapper for the 3rd-party code.
Best practice is to never use the 3rd party code directly, as if it changes you will be forced to perform many changes.

Comment: Thank you for this real interesting comment. Of course a wrapper would cost a lot of time to implement.

Comment: You would probably find out that the time you spend in building the wrapper will ease you'er development later, it normally pays off.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make `pT` and `pU` smart pointers (`std::auto_ptr` in C++98 or `std::unique_ptr` in C++11), throw the errors when you detect them and let the smart pointers do their work on their destruction (that will take place on exception, too).

Comment: I would not even suggest auto_ptr anymore. It's officially deprecated in favour of shared_ptr and unique_ptr.

Comment: @bstamour: I was just trying to offer a non C++11 solution (maybe this was not clear enough in the answer).

Answer (score 1):

For reference (in case you haven't seen it before), here's the C++11 version that uses smart pointers. It's equivalent to your code other than:

- it doesn't leak `pT` in the case where `new U()` throws
- likewise it doesn't leak if anything else throws (constructor of `Q` etc)
- it destroys `myQ` *before* deleting `pU` and then `pT`, whereas your code deletes those first and then destroys `myQ`.

Typically the order of destruction doesn't matter, but it's something to be aware of in case it does matter. If you need to destroy your objects in anything other than reverse order of creation then their lifetimes can't be controlled simply by their scope.

```
void examplefunc()
{
    std::unique_ptr<T> pT(new T());
    std::unique_ptr<U> pU(new U());
    Q myQ;
    int iRes;

    if ((iRes = myQ.func1())!= CONST_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw translateException(iRes);  // providing exc
    }
    if ((iRes = mQ.func2())!= CONST_SUCCESS)
    {
        throw translateException(iRes);  // providing exc 
    }
    return;
}
```

I'm assuming of course that the `T` and `U` objects can't simply be placed on the stack -- you haven't shown why not, but the fact you're asking suggests there's a reason!

This code should not cause any issue at all with mixing raw and smart pointers between new and old code -- this function was previously responsible for freeing what it allocates, and it still is. If you need to pass a pointer to the `T` or `U` objects to some pre-existing code that takes a raw pointer:

- without ownership, then pass `pT.get()`
- with ownership (if this function isn't always responsible for deleting, because sometimes it passes or returns the pointer to someone else with that responsibility), then pass `pT.release()`.

Then you can use smart pointers in more of your existing code as and when you like.

Finally, it's possible to write the above code in C++03 with `std::auto_ptr`, but you do have to be quite careful with `auto_ptr`, it's fairly easy to make mistakes with it. `unique_ptr` is "safer" but can't be fully implemented in C++03. `boost::scoped_ptr` is probably the best bet in C++03 if you don't need `release()`.

Answer (score 0):

Construct T and U on the stack instead of from the heap. Then they get deconstructed automatically. You should do this whenever you possibly can.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to repeat the same stuff over and over write a function that does:

```
void throwErrorAndCleanup(T* pT, U* pU, int iRes)
{
    delete pU;
    delete pT;
    throw translateException(iRes);
}
```

Another way to do this is with goto's. Using goto is a somewhat highly debated topic, however for error cleanup like this it often makes sense (in particular you may find that you need to cleanup more things as the function progresses, so you can create more jump targets that cleanup the extra stuff and then fall into the earlier cleanup).

```
void examplefunc()
{
  T* pT = new T();
  U* pU = new U();
  Q myQ;
  int iRes = CONST_SUCCESS;

  if ((iRes = myQ.func1())!= CONST_SUCCESS)
  {
    goto error;
  }
  if ((iRes = mQ.func2())!= CONST_SUCCESS)
  {
    goto error;
  }

  delete pU;
  delete pT;
  return;

  error:
  delete pU;
  delete pT;
  throw translateException(iRes);  // providing exc 
}
```

Comment: Like I said, the use goto's are hotly debated ;)

Comment: throwErrorAndCleanup(T* pT, U* pU, int iRes)
might be nice for the example, but cannot be used in general of course...

Comment: -1 because this is just poor advice.  This isn't C, C++ provides better methods to manage resources

Comment: @EdS. It's a commonly used paradigm. Often times you will have to do more than just delete pointers. In that case using a goto is very beneficial. If for instance you need to close some resource, simply using smart pointers is not going to solve the problem.

Comment: @CrazyCasta:  I write C++ code every day, it's not commonly used in C++ nor should it be.  It is trivial to create an RAII style wrapper for any sort of scope guided management you need to do, it doesn't have to be used solely for memory management.. There is absolutely no reason to use a goto here, I would suggest you read up a bit on more modern C++ practices.

Comment: @EdS. I have a lot of experience with a lot of C++ code and it is in fact very commonly used. In particular if you need to close a resource on failure but not on success you can't just use scope guidance. You would have to wrap your function in a class of it's own and make it clear to the user that it needs to let the class go out of scope if the function fails. In particular, you're restricting what people can do (they wouldn't be able to make the class global for instance).

Comment: @CrazyCasta: Well, you may commonly use `goto`'s, but it is not commonly used in general, regardless of how many times you say that it is.  You can easily solve for the case you just mentioned by setting a flag, and now you don't need to worry about exceptions and goofy control flow issues.  You are not writing exception safe code, you are not writing code which is as easily maintainable as it could be if you adopted RAII style resource management.

Comment: Tell me this; what happens if `myQ.func1()` or `myQ.func2()` throw an exception?  Your `goto`s are useless and you leak memory.

Comment: @EdS. You seem to have worked on a limited number of projects with a limited number of people. It varies from project to project and from group to group. Not everyone uses RAII style, not everyone uses goto's. It's a matter of preference. Suggesting that there is only one "right" way in C++ is ridiculous. That's like suggest that there's only one "right" OS or language.

Comment: Well that's quite an assumption you've made there, but no, you are wrong.  I've worked on quite a few C++ projects and write safety critical code in my day job.  You're method is just asking for trouble if performance and reliability is crucial.  That code would never pass a review in my company. It's not a matter of preference, one is method clearly and demonstrably better than the other.  I can show you many, many instances in which RAII is clearly superior to a goto.  I don't think you can show me one single instance of the opposite.

Comment: A. The OP suggests that the inner code does not throw exceptions. If this is not the case, or if you want to be exception-safe then you could easily put a try/catch around the if statements.

B. I'm not sure how many companies or groups of people outside your company you've coded with. My point is that style varies from group to group. Sure, your company may have one specific way of doing things, another company may well have another way of doing things. I've probably worked on least 15-20 different projects with different groups of people. Everyone is diff and has a diff way of doing things.

Comment: Ummm... `operator new` throws an exception upon failure, so you already have a potential leak here; `U* pU = new U();`.  Again though... one way is clearly better than the other.  You have still shown me no examples in which a goto should be preferred.  God forbid you ever have to change that code in a way that adds a subtle error condition which the goto doesn't account for.  It doesn't look like we're going to agree here, but seriously; there is a clear choice to be made, and you are making the wrong one.  The fact that you don't even suggest a smart pointer for this situation is laughable.

Comment: I'm simply offering an alternative viewpoint. The fact that you can not see that there is more than one way to skin a cat is truly sad.

Comment: No, what's truly sad is that you write code like this. You have typed a lot of characters without providing a single legitimate reason to prefer a goto over an RAII container in any conceivable situation.  If you can't come up with a single concrete example in your favor then, well, you're wrong.  All you do is repeat how I lack experience over and over again without providing any semblance of a valid argument. I'm not one for religion in software development, but sometimes one choice is just obviously superior to another. I really hope you're not writing mission critical code in any capacity.

Comment: ...ok, that was over the line, I apologize.  We disagree, but that's no excuse for me to attack you personally.  My point is simply that your version contains bugs and poses maintenance problems that a version using an RAII container would not.  I just don't understand how you can defend this approach.